# Export or save audio on Cubase 10.5

Tags: audio, stereo, cubase, export

I’ve been confused by exporting audio files in cubase. I export a stereo audio file and I get a mono one. Just a moment ago I tried *saving* the file and it’s fast and in stereo. 
Does anyone have a comment on this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Based on Nuendo...

You should be able to do an Export -> Audio Mixdown which will allow you to select an output channel of a particular format (mono, stereo, whatever) to allow you to export the audio through that master channel. This is a fairly basic process in cubendo. "Saving" is normally done at a project level. You need to 'export audio mixdown' in order to get the entire signal chain into the process.